# Missing elements when importing XML info Excel

Tags: xml, excel

I've got the following XML file:

```
<toc label="My information" href="index.html">
  <topic label="Main page 1" href="topics/one.html">
    <topic label="1a" href="topics/1a.html"/>
    <topic label="1b" href="topics/1b.html"/>
  </topic>
  <topic label="Main page 2" href="topics/two.html">
    <topic label="2a" href="topics/2a.html"/>
    <topic label="2b" href="topics/2b.html"/>
  </topic>
</toc>
```

When I import into Excel 2016, I get this:
[image]

This is great, except that I was expecting to get a row each for "Main page 1" and "Main page 2". How can I get Excel to include these rows?

Answer (score 0):

I worked around this by running the XML through an XSL that duplicates all nodes that have children:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="xml"/>

<xsl:template match="toc">
  <topic label="{@label}" href="{@topic}">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </topic>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="topic">
  <topic label="{@label}" href="{@href}">
  <!-- if topic has children, insert another copy here -->
  <xsl:if test="topic">
    <topic label="{@label}" href="{@href}"/>
  </xsl:if>
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </topic>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```